# What is the maximum number of lambdas used in one Java class?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, jvm

This is a purely conceptual question.

Lambdas in Java 8 are converted to methods that get invoked using the `invokedynamic`.

If there is a JVM limitation for a maximum number of methods that one class can have, does this mean that the maximum number of lambdas used in one class is also strictly limited by JVM?

Is this question pretty much equal to this one? [What is the maximum number of methods a Java class can have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342072/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-methods-a-java-class-can-have)

Comment: "Lambdas in Java 8 are converted to methods that get invoked using the `invokedynamic`."---this is incorrect. Only lambda _creation_ sites have `invokedynamic` which allows the runtime to choose the strategy of creation on each site. Lambas themselves are converted to instances of ad-hoc classes which implement the required interface with the lambda method.

Comment: OTOH, some kinds of lambdas do result in the addition of methods to the declaring class. The limit on that is easy to google, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342072/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-methods-a-java-class-can-have

Comment: The java class format has a limit of 64K constants and this will limit the number of lambdas (and constants/method calls) you can refer to in one class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Java Language Specification does not mandate a limit, so we only have technical limitations on that. The specification also doesn’t mandate a particular compiled form, so even the technical limitations are fuzzy.

Lambda expressions are compiled into methods of the class file hosting the body of the lambda expression, but this isn’t strictly required. Most notably, simple expression of the form `foo -> bar(foo)` could get compiled like method references. Further, identical lambda expressions could get compiled using the same method. This is an optimization that doesn’t currently happen and it also makes debugging harder, but in principle, it is allowed.

Also, a smart compiler could start generating auxiliary classes hosting lambda bodies, when it detects the unlikely case that the limit is about to be reached.

With the current straight-forward implementation, the maximum number of methods, i.e. 65535, affects the maximum number of possible lambda expressions, but this doesn’t imply that we can create 65535 lambda expressions.

For example, there must be at least one (source code) method containing the lambda expression, which will create the instance of the functional interface. The minimum instruction size of a creation site is a sole `invokedynamic` instruction having five bytes¹. Since the maximum code size of a method is 65535 and we need at least one by for the `return` instruction, there can be at most `65534/5 == 13106` lambda expressions in one method, so trying to create more requires to place them in different methods, reducing the number of methods available to lambda expressions. You can work-around this by using nested lambda expressions, i.e. `x -> y -> z`, [but even nesting has practical limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112260/2711488).

The current compilers use naming schemes that produce unique names for each synthetic method, so they need individual constant pool entries. So having unique implementation methods, each lambda creation site will need an entry for the name, the name&type referring to the name, a “MethodRef” referring to the name&type and the (always the same) declaration class, a method handle referring to the “MethodRef” and an invokedynamic entry referring to the method handle. This make a total of five constant pool entries per lambda expression and since the constant pool is limited to 65534 entries, and we need some entries for other purposes, the calculation is 65500/5, so **with the current compiler implementations the maximum number of lambda expressions is 13,100**. Assuming they all have the same signature…

In a practice test with `javac` (1.8u111) I could compile a class file with 13,098 lambda expressions of the same signature and even exactly 13,100 with generation of debugging symbols disabled, before the error “too many constants” appeared. In that test class, I put the lambda expressions into two constructors, as at least one constructor must be present anyway and both can share the name entry. I think, you can’t get more with a standard compiler.

---

If you want to lift the limitation imposed by the naming scheme, you still have to adhere to the rule that each method must be distinguishable, so it must differ at least by either, name or signature, from other methods. If you try to reach the theoretical maximum, you’ll have to combine *n* distinct method names with *m* distinct signatures to allow `n×m` distinct methods, so 65535 methods will require at least 256 name entries and 256 signature entries. You still have unique name&type combinations, so you will need the other four entries per lambda expressions, ending up with 16,247 possible lambda expressions. Since these are far less than 65535, you can cope with lesser name&type combinations, i.e. combine 128 names with 128 signatures, having more entries for the creation sites, i.e. having 16311 possible lambda expression. Some more if you abuse the signature strings as method names (which works on the byte code level, as long as the signatures don’t contain reference types).

For (significantly) more, you have to stop generating distinct methods for each lambda expression.

---

¹ that would make valid bytecode. On source code level, lambda expression aren’t statements, so more code, e.g. an assignment to a variable, is required.

Comment: Seems if lambda names and signatures are long, a java class can hold even less lambda expression. In my case , if I add one more lambda, java compiler will throw 'code too large', but if I change this lambda to a factory method call, compile will success.